# Python/Pandas - Retrieve most recent event for given row

Tags: python, pandas

Good afternoon,

I have the following two tables and would like to get for each id, the most recent event that occured (in the past).

Example:

```
id | start_date
1, 2017-01-03
2, 2017-01-05
3, 2017-01-10
```

and

```
id | event_date | event
1, 2017-01-03, AskForPayment
1, 2017-01-04, Paid
2, 2017-01-03, AskForPayment
2, 2017-01-03, Paid
2, 2017-01-07, AskForPayment
3, 2017-01-13, Paid
```

Output:

```
id | start_date | event_date | event
1, 2017-01-03, 2017-01-03, AskForPayment
2, 2017-01-05, 2017-01-03, Paid
3, 2017-01-10, Nan, Nan
```

Many thanks!

Comment: you are looking for `pd.merge_asof`

Comment: why is the expect output NaN for `id=3`?